# capturar coordenadas del mouse dentro de un form utilizando otro

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net

Estoy intentando actualizar una aplicación en la cual quiero que los usuarios puedan automatizar ciertas acciones (Clicks).

Esta aplicación ya esta a un 75% y se realizo en `C#`, `Winform` y `.net 4.5.2`

***Nota:** no puedo plantear hacer cambios en la lógica (Código) ya que esto acarrea irrumpir en código que ya es funcional y que me han indicado no tocar, por otro lado lo que me solicitaron fue, para este proceso permite que el usuario automatice el role/ejecución bajo su supervisión*

Teniendo estas consideraciones explico la estructura; a partir de dos form:

- form 1: Main Form
- form 2: Setting Form
- form 3: ActionClick (form que hace el tracking del mouse)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Problema:**
Estoy intentando que a partir del form 1 poder llamar al form 2; el form 2 es una interface para usuario en donde puede automatizar el evento click del mouse; pero sucede que cada formulario o vista que se va a desplegar en el form 1 tiene los botones del crud en lugares distinto (varia, incluso es dinámico según el monitor o espacio de trabajo), entonces estoy implementando un tercer form para hacer el tracking del mouse.

**Pregunta:**
Como puedo obtener las coordenadas del mouse relativas al form 1 desde el form 2 o 3; para luego guardarlas y que las pueda usar para hacer los click automatizados que sean necesarios, Actualmente he logrado esto pero no termina de ser funcional ya que es relativo a la pantalla y busco que sea relativo al form 1.

**Como llamo a los forms 1, 2 y 3**
el form 2 lo estoy llamando con:

```
AppSetting configForm = new AppSetting();
configForm.ShowDialog();
```

Cuando entro a el Form 2: y quiero rastrear el cursor hago al hacer click en el boton **Pick**:

```
Visible = false;
ActionClick ActionClickArea = new ActionClick();
ActionClickArea.Show();
```

el Form 3 que se encarga de hacer el tracking del cursor en la pantalla este tiene algunos problemas:

1. no logro super ponerlo al form 1, terminan teniendo un tamaño distinto o en el caso de pantallas multiples si el form 1 esta la pantalla extendidad #2, el form 3 (este) sigue apareciendo en la pantalla #1.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MetaBootKPMG.forms
{
    public partial class ActionClick : Form
    {
        public Bitmap CursorRed = new Bitmap(4, 4);
        public Mutex Checking = new Mutex(false);
        public AutoResetEvent Are = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        public Thread TrackerThread;

        public AppSetting AppSettingForm;

        public ActionClick()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ActionClick_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Opacity = 0.10;
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    CursorRed.SetPixel(i, j, Color.Red);
                }
            }
            
            Cursor = CreateCursor(CursorRed, new Size(decimal.ToInt32(5), decimal.ToInt32(5)));
            TopMost = true;
            MouseTracker();
        }

        private void MouseTracker()
        {
            if (Checking.WaitOne(10))
            {
                var ctx = new SynchronizationContext();
                Are.Reset();
                TrackerThread = new Thread(() => {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (Are.WaitOne(1))
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        if (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left)
                        {
                            ctx.Send(CLickFromOutside, null);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                });
                TrackerThread.Start();
                Checking.ReleaseMutex();
            }
        }

        private void CLickFromOutside(object state)
        {
            Are.Set();
            int X = MousePosition.X;
            int Y = MousePosition.Y;

            AppSettingForm.textBox5.Text = X.ToString();
            AppSettingForm.textBox6.Text = Y.ToString();

        }

        public static Cursor CreateCursor(Bitmap Bmap, Size SizeC)
        {
            Bmap = new Bitmap(Bmap, SizeC);
            Bmap.MakeTransparent();
            return new Cursor(Bmap.GetHicon());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso acarrea que hay que estaquear el form 3 sobre el form 1:

```
var screen = Screen.FromPoint(Cursor.Position);
StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
Location = screen.Bounds.Location;
Left = Form1.Left;
Top = Form1.Top;
Size = Form1.Size;
```

Se hace con:

```
Point relativePoint = PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
```